# How can I convince someone that flying is safe?

Tags: aircraft

My fiance is very scared of flying, and the constant media attention given to plane crashes doesn't help her phobia at all. In fact, the recent EgyptAir plane crash has made her attempt to swear off flying from her life altogether. Obviously it's hard to live without flying nowadays. It's just too convenient to abandon.

What can I do to encourage her and tell her that flying is safe and we shouldn't give up on it just because of the very occasional plane crash?

Comment: A) Terrorists intend to instill terror. Are you letting them win? B) Every month 2-3000 people die in a car accident in the USA alone. Will you stop driving?

Comment: You might want to see whether this has been addressed at http://aviation.stackexchange.com

Comment: A short answer: Xanax can do that for you.

Comment: @phoog Most questions about being a passenger on a commercial flight are off-topic at [Aviation.se] and this question has already been [closed as off-topic](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/27655/946), there.

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis does Xanax help with getting the person to agree to fly? David R: thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Let her watch a flight simulation video. It's entertaining and she can see what happens in the cockpit, how they fly and so on. It helped me. [A video I like](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYJNEeVoRZA)

Answer (score 1):

Some airlines have offered a "fear of flying" course, that includes a short domestic flight at "graduation".

Unfortunately, while statistics bear out that aviation is safer than car travel, the human mind sometimes has a hard time bypassing the emotional for the logical.  Car wrecks which we read about / see all the time are always just a couple of people, no big deal to the emotions, but when a plane goes down it is hundreds of causalities and in the headlines for days.  And for some people the emotional side of the news totally outweighs the logical side of reality.

And while drugs help calm the nerves once on the plane, you still need to convince her to get on the plane.

You can only try to appeal to her logic, through out figures such as the US airline Delta has almost 2 million flights per year, the SkyTeam alliance has some 6 million flights per year, the three major alliances (Star, SkyTeam, OneWorld) together have 17 million flights per year. All this versus a few crashes.